# How do I build the HTML properly for a layout with various background images with content laid on top of it?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site with various background images with content laid on top of it. The way I have it now is not working because when I view the site on a mobile browser, some of the elements get pushed to the left leaving an ugly white space on the right.

This is because the elements that are being pushed aren't contained within a wrapper. However, I am not sure how to lay out all of the elements especially with the various background images that they need to be laid upon.

I've created a simple image of how the divs are laid out.

Note: All the text `100% width, etc` is referring to the divs under the red transparent boxes (the content). The actual site can be viewed [here](http://keebs.com/sandbox).

[image]

Can someone help me figure out how I should build the HTML properly for the layout of this website? For example, should I split the top half and bottom half to `#top` and `#bottom` with a wrapper within each? I'm stuck as to how I should approach this.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that all your widths are based on pixels when (for responsive results) should be percentages.

What is ruining your iPhone layout seems to be the pinboard ID at 1122px with a margin of 47px. That is much wider than the other divs above and below.

However, fixed layouts can be applicable to mobile. See -> [fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)

Comment: What's confusing me, though, is that `#slide` (within `#slide-bg`) is wider than `#pinboard` at 1174px. Does this mean that I should wrap all of the elements in a 1174px wide wrapper?

Comment: Seems that your site is being worked on at the moment. Usually you your "content" div is centered, has margin 0 auto, a max-width set by pixels (ie 960px) and 100% width. each div inside will get percentage widths that readjust per screen size. Your website doesn't seem to be built that way.

Comment: Please make this the answer if I helped at all @Desi. Someone voted me down for trying to help...